# What is the default C++ version used in Android?

Tags: android, c++, android-library, platform

What is the default C++ version used in Android?

there are posts like "Enable C++11 support on Android" but how to find default version.

Android libraries are application programming or system programming?

Answer (score 1):

For android system programming:
Determines the C++ version that the gcc tool version used in the android operating system supports.
You can check here for gcc version :"android/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.7/SOURCES" file.
Also you can see here what the gcc version supports.
[enter link description here](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html)